# Como detectar alteração no value do input com readonly ativo

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<!-- Campo preenchido com retorno AJAX -->
<input type="text" name="estado-cliente" hidden id="estado-cliente"  readonly="readonly"/>
```

Como faço parar detectar qualquer alteração no `value`?

Obs.: o `value` é adicionado e alterado via JS

**Sem sucesso com o trecho abaixo**:

```
$("#estado-cliente").bind("change paste keyup", function() {});
```

Answer (score -1):

Adicione no seu JavaScript o seguinte

```
$("#estado-cliente').on('change', function () {
  alert("Estão tentando alterar");
});
```